# Bootstrap dropdown css and input field inside the dropdown only can enter digit

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have input field inside a dropdown css and I am using bootstrap 4. when I enter some character I am not able to enter but I am able to input numbers. How to solve this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown" data-dropdown="true">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-boundary="viewport">Spot</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 300px;" data-loaded="true" data-selectedvalues="S">
    <input placeholder="Search...Type" type="search">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item active" data-selectedvalues="S">Spot</button>
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" data-selectedvalues="T">Term</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide the code from your dropdown

Comment: full code?.......

Comment: I made a snippet. Your code seems to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue. There was a event listener for document level for a particular class input. It will fire every time I press the character key. The script was on some other file so was not able to find out. I thought it was a bootsrap feature initially.